# Почему Python внезапно начал печать в поиске слеши(/) вместо букв?

Tags: python-3.x

коллеги!
Программа должна открыть "Пуск", ввести "notepad", нажать интер. и т.д.
ВНЕЗАПНО! начала писать в поиск следующее: /////___/

вот код:

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time
import os
pg.hotkey('winleft')
time.sleep(2_)
pg.typewrite('notepad\n', 0.1)
expect = 'test'
pg.typewrite(expect, 0.1)
pg.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(1)
name = 'testFile'
path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Учёба IBS\\Python_HW\\' + name

if os.path.exists(name):
    os.remove(name)

pg.typewrite(path + '\n', 0.1)
actual = ''
with open(path) as inf:
    actual = inf.readline()

if expect == actual:
    print('passed')
else:
    print('failed')

pg.hotkey('alt', 'F4')
```

PS так прога не работает, что за конструкция: `pg.typewrite('notepad\n', 0.1)` , т.е. что именно значит 0,1?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0,1 - это интервал задержки между нажатиями каждой символьной клавиши.

Comment: Да, прога ВНЕЗАПНО снова заработала, и я выяснил это опытным путём. Спасибо!